# SIP Registration on asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, registration

Remote computer with static ip trying to register on my asterisk(1.8).
peer settings:

```
[remotepeer]
type = peer
host = dynamic
insecure = port,invite
context = remotepeer-Inbound
directmedia = no
dtmfmode = rfc2833
callcounter = yes
nat = no
contactpermit=1.1.1.1/32
permit=1.1.1.0/24
username = remotepeer
secret = remotepeerpass
```

When the peer is registering i got:

```
[Apr 13 10:15:55] WARNING[23037]: chan_sip.c:14609 parse_register_contact: Domain '1.1.1.1:5060' disallowed by contact ACL (violating IP 1.1.1.1)
[Apr 13 10:15:55] WARNING[23037]: chan_sip.c:15394 register_verify: Registration denied because of contact ACL`
```

When I set `dynamic_exclude_static = no` the peer is registering.
I dont want to allow registration from any IP.
How to set `dynamic_exclude_static = yes` and allow the registration for peer(ip of that peer is fixed)?

Comment: So what you want to get from SO community? Have you check sip debug? Have you checked in asterisk debug what chan_sip do?

Comment: @arheops yes I checked. There is the same log. Only the last packet differs. If `dynamic_exclude_static = yes` last packet is 603 denied and there is the message  `parse_register_contact: Domain '1.1.1.1:5060' disallowed by contact ACL (violating IP 1.1.1.1)` before it. if `dynamic_exclude_static = no`  last packet is 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have `host=dynamic` ... have you tried `host = 1.1.1.1`, since you don't want dynamic registrations anyway?

Comment: if the parameter is not  `host = dynamic` asterisk think`s that peer is without registration.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you post a link to a screen-cap?